# Formatting Arabic date value to a string: new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar'); => 'ddyyyy/m/'

Tags: javascript

Why `toLocaleDateString` with `ar` locale returns the date string in `ddyyyy/m/` format?

Is `ddyyyy/m/` legit date format in standard Arabic culture? Never seen a format like that.

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar');

=> "15‏/1‏/2021"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rootnode/wtc1mson/1/

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like a valid date format. But for locale 'ar-SA' and others, it gives the proper output.

Comment: It can tested for example with `fi` or `it`. They give a proper output.

Answer (score 1):

Stored the formated date string in a variable and consoled chars, it is not `ddyyyy/mm/`, instead there are some special characters in-between. So the actual format is `dd/mm/yyyy + right to left chars`.

```
const str = new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar');
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {console.log(str[i])}

//Output
"1"
"5"
"‏"
"/"
"1"
"‏"
"/"
"2"
"0"
"2"
"1"
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tsfahmad/wjq54o1a/

And then I also checked the charCode

```
str.charCodeAt(i);
49
53
8207 //<- It is right-to-left mark
47
49
8207 // <- Same (https://www.codetable.net/decimal/8207)
47
50
48
50
49
```

Answer (score 1):

The returned date is with right-to-left code. See below when inserted into a div element, it will show correctly.

```js
let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar');

document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = today;
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" dir="rtl"> </div>
```