# date.toLocaleDateString conversion with locale Arabic yields different results in Chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, right-to-left

I have a function that formats date using date.toLocaleDateString
I see that when I have locale set to 'Arabic' the results in Chrome are different from what is on FF and Safari.

```js
let date = new Date();
const dateOptions = {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
};

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("ar", dateOptions));
```

Here is the code-sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-haslett-mj6b0?file=/src/index.js

In chrome, date shows up as 27‏/01‏/2021  whereas in FF and Safari, it is converted to Arabic.

How can we ensure consistency across browsers?

Comment: Code should be posted **here**, not on an external site.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and the snippet within, to add a definition for `date`; then people can run it for themselves.

Comment: @Kimaya did you click the "run code snippet" button? Your code does not work.

Comment: @Pointy I added the snippet :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting Arabic date value to a string: new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar'); => 'ddyyyy/m/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65732477/formatting-arabic-date-value-to-a-string-new-date-tolocaledatestringar)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ar-eg` instead of just `ar`:

```js
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("ar-eg", dateOptions));
```

But remember that the `toLocaleDateString` implentation is always application dependent, furthermore there are browsers that do not implement the `locale`/`option` parameters.

You can check the language and options support by using the following functions:

```js
function dateSupportsLocales(language) {
  try {
    new Date().toLocaleDateString(language);
  } catch (e) {
    return e.name !== 'RangeError';
  }
  return true;
}

function dateSupportsOptions() {
  try {
    new Date().toLocaleDateString('en', {});
    return true;
  }
  catch (e) { }
  return false;
}
```

Check also the `Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString` [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for more informations.

Comment: no need to add locale by country. See the above example solution. Need to state the numbering system.

Comment: @Mohsen Alyafei thank you for your comment. As stated in the answer, this method is implementation dependant, numbering system could not be supported on older browsers, while sublocales are much more spread (ie7 supports sublocales such as ar-eg but not numbering systems). A further reading could be this: [DateTimeFormat (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 0):

You are not explicitly stating the `numberingSystem` and you leave it to the browser implementation to decide.

if you state the `numberingSystem` as `arab` then you get consistent results:

Here is an example:

Just add `u-nu-arab` after the locale `ar`. No need to give a country code.

```js
let date = new Date();
const dateOptions = {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
};

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("ar-u-nu-arab", dateOptions));
```